# Thunderbird inbox: How to auto-scroll to latest email in incoming list?

Tags: thunderbird

my emails in Thunderbird (V 17.0.2 on Win 8) are sorted by date, the newest mails are on the bottom of the inbox-list.

I want this behavior: As soon as new emails show up in my inbox, the inbox-list shall directly scroll to the newest emails on the bottom of the inbox list. Currently new incoming emails are added to the inbox-list in the correct date-order BUT the list does not auto-scroll to the last (newest) element in this list. I always have to manually scroll down to see the new incoming emails as they are just below my second-newest emails from my previous mail-fetch.

Alternative way to solve my problem and to clarify: After the email-fetch-task has finished, I would need a plugin that automatically presses the END-key on the keyboard (above the cursor keys).

Is it possible to enable this behavior maybe by a special config-flag in "about:config" (edit configuration)?

Thank you a lot!!!

Thomas

Comment: You know that if you order you mails so that the newest are at the top then Thunderbird will auto-scroll to show new emails?

Comment: I think the best thing you can do is sort descendingly. You might find it at: Tools > Options > Advanced > General > Config Editor. Filter by 'mailnews.default' in the Filter bar and change values 1 (Ascending) by 2 (Descending). 
It only affects folders which are first opened after this tweak but there's a way to make it work for existing folders as well. Close Thunderbird, go to your Thunderbird profile folder, delete all .msf files, and open Thunderbird again.

Answer (score 2):

At this moment the behavior reported is a know bug [xref bugzilla #539468](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=539468) and there is not much to do